# How to reset webpush permission

Tags: javascript, push-notification, web-push

I am requesting permission to show notification to a user after logging in and saving the endpoint to that user.

In some rare case, the page may be redirected to login page and user will be logged out with the browser's request popup still showing. If the user clicks allow then, I will not consider the endpoint because I cannot associate it to any user.

After the user logs in again, I want to request permission even if the permission is `granted`. How do I reset the permission set by user in the login page, if its Allow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot revoke the browser permission.

Usually you need to store the endpoint on your server and remove it when you don't need that (but you don't revoke the browser permission). Then when you want you can display a prompt again (not the native prompt, just a custom prompt designed with HTML / CSS).